# Efficient way to compute pairwise euclidean distances between all vectors in a tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, vectorization, tensorflow2.0, array-broadcasting

Let `feature_map` be a tensor with shape: `b,h,w,c = feature_map.shape`

To calculate pairwise euclidean distances between all vectors in the channels (c) axis I use the following code:

```
feature_map = tf.reshape(feature_map,(b,-1,c))
norms = []
for i in range(h*w):
    norm = tf.norm(feature_map-feature_map[:,i:i+1,:],ord=2,axis=-1)
    norms.append(sorted_tensor)
norms = tf.stack(norms,axis=1)
```

This procedure is very slow. To avoid `for-loop` I tried to use `tf.tile` to make copies of the tensor and then apply the `norm` function but resulted in memory errors because the generated tensor was very large.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Euclidean Distance Matrix Trick from [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~albanie/notes/Euclidean_distance_trick.pdf)

The `numpy` adaption is the following:

```
feature_map = tf.reshape(feature_map,(b,-1,c))         
G = np.einsum('bik, bjk->bij', feature_map, feature_map)
D = G.diagonal(axis1=1,axis2=2).reshape(b,-1,1)+ np.transpose(G.diagonal(axis1=1,axis2=2).reshape(b,-1,1),axes=(0,2,1)) - 2*G
norms = np.sqrt(D)
```

and the corresponding `tensorflow` adaptation:

```
feature_map = tf.reshape(feature_map,(b,-1,c))     
G = tf.einsum('bik, bjk->bij', feature_map, feature_map)
D = tf.reshape(tf.linalg.diag_part(G),(b,-1,1))+ tf.transpose(tf.reshape(tf.linalg.diag_part(G),(b,-1,1)),perm=(0,2,1)) - 2*G
norms = tf.sqrt(D)
```